# Amazon EC2 - set Windows services log on user to another instance user

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012

I have a master "share drive" on a single Windows Server 2012 instance that many secondary instances are mapped to with full control. I have a service that I need to set with administrator rights to the master share drive.

When I enter the Administrator password, it only finds the current location/instance. How do I connect to another instance from the services "log on as" tab? Clicking on the browse location tab only shows the local instance.

The share drive is set to all users full control but for some reason, the service does not follow that rule and is denied permission.

Comment: Are you using a domain to manage your permissions are all of these user accounts on the individual machines?

Comment: Hi Kate, each machine just has an Admin account. I'm using a service for Backburner, a 3D rendering startup script. For some reason, I get a permission denied when it runs as the local Admin, but when I stop the service and run the program in manual mode, permissions are fine. So I'm hoping it just has to do with it saying "./Administrator" in the logon as box.